# May I fetch the API on the .ts (TypeScript) files?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, api, react-hooks

The template I bought; Many files have `.tsx` and `.ts` extensions as they are prepared with technologies such as React and Typescript. Among them are the `.ts` and `.json` files under the `Data` folder, which contain demo content.

The logic is as follows: There are data belonging to the demo content in the `.json` files, and the `.ts` files below them contain variable structures to pull the data from the `.json` files.
What I want is this: Can I pull each data from these files again by applying API calls and map operations? Is this possible or do I need to do something else?

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

This is demo .json file sample as __post.json:

```
[
  {
    "index": 1,
    "id": "9e3e3994-a3ed-47ca-a014-d4483884cfe2",
    "featuredImage": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440778303588-435521a205bc?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80",
    "title": "Lenovo’s smarter devices stoke professional passions ",
    "desc": "Aenean lectus. Pellentesque eget nunc. Donec quis orci eget orci vehicula condimentum.",
    "date": "May 20, 2021",
    "href": "/single/this-is-single-slug",
    "commentCount": 11,
    "viewdCount": 2504,
    "readingTime": 2,
    "bookmark": { "count": 3007, "isBookmarked": false },
    "like": { "count": 3366, "isLiked": true },
    "authorId": 3,
    "categoriesId": [3, 12],
    "postType": "standard"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "id": "af92a665-4a4d-4cff-9e17-89456df21fb5",
    "featuredImage": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489753735160-2cbf3d9006d4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
    "title": "How AI and Teams are benefitting the littlest of patients ",
    "desc": "In sagittis dui vel nisl. Duis ac nibh. Fusce lacus purus, aliquet at, feugiat non, pretium quis, lectus.",
    "date": "May 20, 2021",
    "href": "/single/this-is-single-slug",
    "commentCount": 13,
    "viewdCount": 1646,
    "readingTime": 5,
    "bookmark": { "count": 3751, "isBookmarked": false },
    "like": { "count": 3024, "isLiked": false },
    "authorId": 4,
    "categoriesId": [4, 13],
    "postType": "video",
    "videoUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5afsxvz75c"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "id": "dffe0224-ebff-4803-bb66-e8d128656284",
    "featuredImage": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1418854982207-12f710b74003?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80",
    "title": "DIYer and TV host Trisha Hershberger’s journey through gaming keeps evolving",
    "desc": "Integer tincidunt ante vel ipsum. Praesent blandit lacinia erat. Vestibulum sed magna at nunc commodo placerat.",
    "date": "May 20, 2021",
    "href": "/single/this-is-single-slug",
    "commentCount": 33,
    "viewdCount": 4031,
    "readingTime": 2,
    "bookmark": { "count": 76, "isBookmarked": false },
    "like": { "count": 222, "isLiked": false },
    "authorId": 4,
    "categoriesId": [4, 13],
    "postType": "standard"
  },]
```

This is the post.ts file where I want to make the API calls:

```
// FOR MAIN DEMO
const DEMO_POSTS = __posts.map((post): PostDataType => {
  //  ##########  GET CATEGORY BY CAT ID ######## //
  const categories = post.categoriesId.map(
    (id) => DEMO_CATEGORIES.filter((taxonomy) => taxonomy.id === id)[0]
  );

  return {
    ...post,
    author: DEMO_AUTHORS.filter((user) => user.id === post.authorId)[0],
    categories: [categories[0]],
  } as PostDataType;
});

// FOR POST TYPE GALLERY
const DEMO_POSTS_GALLERY = __postsGallery.map((post): PostDataType => {
  //  ##########  GET CATEGORY BY CAT ID ######## //
  const categories = post.categoriesId.map(
    (id) => DEMO_CATEGORIES.filter((taxonomy) => taxonomy.id === id)[0]
  );

  return {
    ...post,
    author: DEMO_AUTHORS.filter((user) => user.id === post.authorId)[0],
    categories: [categories[0]],
  } as PostDataType;
});

// FOR POST TYPE VIDEO
const DEMO_POSTS_VIDEO = __postsVideo.map((post): PostDataType => {
  //  ##########  GET CATEGORY BY CAT ID ######## //
  const categories = post.categoriesId.map(
    (id) => DEMO_CATEGORIES.filter((taxonomy) => taxonomy.id === id)[0]
  );

  return {
    ...post,
    author: DEMO_AUTHORS.filter((user) => user.id === post.authorId)[0],
    categories: [categories[0]],
  } as PostDataType;
});

// FOR POST TYPE AUDIO
const DEMO_POSTS_AUDIO = __postsAudio.map((post): PostDataType => {
  //  ##########  GET CATEGORY BY CAT ID ######## //
  const categories = post.categoriesId.map(
    (id) => DEMO_CATEGORIES.filter((taxonomy) => taxonomy.id === id)[0]
  );

  return {
    ...post,
    author: DEMO_AUTHORS.filter((user) => user.id === post.authorId)[0],
    categories: [categories[0]],
  } as PostDataType;
});

export { DEMO_POSTS, DEMO_POSTS_AUDIO, DEMO_POSTS_GALLERY, DEMO_POSTS_VIDEO };
```

Bonus: An example I wrote for my own trial and it works partially.

```
export const getPosts = async (slug: string) => {
  const posts: PostDataType[] = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/list`).then(res => res.json());

  return posts
    .map((post): PostDataType => {
      const categories = post.categoryId.map(
        (id) => DEMO_CATEGORIES.filter((taxonomy) => taxonomy.id === id)[0]
      );

      return {
        ...post,
        author: DEMO_AUTHORS.filter((user) => user.id === post.authorId)[0],
        categories: [categories[0]],
      } as PostDataType;
    });
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do here.  In that final snippet what do you mean "it works partially"? What does that code do when run? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: My friend is like this: I wrote this code for testing purposes only to see if I can perform fetch operations and the API call was successful, but I will need to print the data obtained from here on the necessary pages using parameters such as useState, useEffect. I know this too, I'm just asking if I can make API calls through these files and perform map operations. Also, I think I was being very descriptive when asking the question. However to be more clear, the data coming out of this page creates a static system, but at this point I want to make them dynamic using API.

Comment: You can call `fetch` from any javascript code that runs in the browser, in any file, at any time, for any reason. And you can `map` over anything iterable (like arrays) anywhere you can run any javascript code as well.  So for the question "Can I pull each data from these files again by applying API calls and map operations?" the answer is "yes". But I'm not sure how to elaborate on to help you without better understanding your actual goal.